# Command Binding works in designer/VS, but not build/release

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, simple-mvvm

I may be overlooking something obvious here, but I can't see it for the life of me right now.

I've got an interaction on a user control (data grid) which has an item source bound to an ICollectionView, but the DataContext is inherited from the parent window:

```
<DataGrid Margin="0" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsView}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        ....
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OnNotifyPeg}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</DataGrid>
```

The DataContext is inherited from the parent window, which has a tabbed view:

```
<Window x:Class="ConfigBrowser.Views.ConfigView"
    DataContext="{Binding ConfigViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
    <Grid Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightBrushKey}}">
        <TabControl Height="Auto" Width="Auto"
                    Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightBrushKey}}">
            <TabItem Header="Overview">
                <controls:Overview/>
            </TabItem>
```

For now, the OnNotifyPeg command just opens a window (via a service, but also a messagebox to debug for now)

```
public ICommand OnNotifyPeg
{
    get { return new DelegateCommand(NotifyPeg); }

}

public void NotifyPeg()
{
    MessageBox.Show("Notify peg", "Clicked");
    _detailService.ViewPeg(SelectedItem);
}
```

Whilst running from within Visual Studio, it works fine - the uc fires off the Command.

But when I run from the Debug or Release folders, nothing happens. No error, no window, nothing - as far as I can tell, it's not bound in the built application?

Edit: Also to add, the columns still load their data fine from the ItemSource (Which uses the data context).

Edit 2: If I move the data grid out of a user control and put it into the tab directly, it's doing the same behaviour. So I don't think it's related to that.

Edit 3: Solved in comments - looks like Costura fails at embedding System.Windows.Interactivity.

Comment: Clean the soultion and again build

Comment: Tried that, as well as closing VS.

Comment: do you have System.window.Interactiv on your debug folder.

Comment: No, but it's (Apparently) being included via Costura.Fody, I'll try explicitly adding it..

Comment: yes add it and use that one for EventTrigger

Comment: So it does work if the dll's in the file, but then that defeats the whole point of using Costura to include dlls in the exe. Now to find out why this fails for this dll only (But works on others)

Comment: So that's the prob right ?

Comment: Yes, kind of. It seems costura doesn't embed the dll correctly, so I need to manually include it, which is less than ideal but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the reference of `system.windows.interactivity` and then use it for `EventTrigger`